# How to deploy Flask API using Apache on domain controlled network?

Tags: javascript, python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm just staring to learn Apache, JavaScript, CSS and Flask and MOD_WSGI for less than a week.

I have this simple project to get data from Oracle database by typing a lot number then display the result to the webpage.
*(I already made this project thru pure python but I want to share to the team thru webserver).*

I have successfully created a webpage and get data from Oracle DB thru Flask API and MOD_WSGI then display back the result using my company laptop and a pc.

[image]

My problems are:

1. When I deployed this project thru Apache2.4 using this PC, the clients can access the page but unable to get data from the database. They encountered ERR_CONNECTION REFUSED based on the console.
   [image]
2. Is this because the server PC is with firewall enabled and controlled by admin? Any solution for this?
3. Or, is there something wrong with my configurations?
4. How to access the page using a ServerName like 'getwbspcdb.com'? I can only access the home page by IP address like 192.168.0.100.

Below are my configurations:

http.conf:

```
LoadFile "C:/Users/a0504128/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python310.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Users/a0504128/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp310-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Users/a0504128/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310"

Listen 192.168.0.107:80 
ServerName getwbspc.com:80

<VirtualHost *:5000>
    ServerAdmin jagon
    ServerName getwbspc_api.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/Apache24/htdocs/SPC/getSPC.wsgi"
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/"
    <Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/SPC">
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Other settings are set to default.

.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/SPC')
from getwbspc_api import app as application
```

API code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
#CORS(app, resources = {r'/api/wbSPC/{smsLot_Number}': {'origins' : 'http://192.168.0.107'}})

#Log Configuration
handler = RotatingFileHandler('api.log', maxBytes=100000, backupCount=10)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)


@app.errorhandler(500)
def internal_server_error(error):
    app.logger.info('This is an info log message:, %s', error, exc_info=True)
    return 'Internal Server Error', 500

@app.route('/api/wbSPC/<smsLot_Number>', methods=['GET'])

def connectDB(smsLot_Number):
    dsn = '''DSN Settings'''
    try:
        connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user = 'xxxx', password = 'xxxx', dsn = dsn)
        if connection:
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            sql_script = ''' SQL query goes here'''
        else:
            return jsonify({'status':'Not Connected'}
    except cx_Oracle.Error as error:
        return jsonify({'status':'Error'})

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug = True)
```

Finally my JS:

```
function getWBSPC_Data(smsLot) {
//let smsLot_Number = document.getElementById('smsLotInput').value;
let smsLot_Number = smsLot;
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/wbSPC/' + smsLot_Number)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(jsonData  => {.................
```

*Apologies, it's a little bit long, I have hard time to summarize and make it shorter.*

I need more time to learn but I'm desperate to implement the project. I google already but haven't found the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Which bit of code is throwing the error?

Comment: @ChristopherJones I cannot find the reason of the error. I can only see it on client browser console. But there's no error showing on the server. Is there a way to trace the error net :: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED from the client?